# Importing large content with Feeds and cron

Tags: 7, feeds

I've used the migrate module in the past, it's great to import large amounts of content but it's pretty complex.
This time I'm trying Feeds and Feeds_SQL to import from a mysql tables. It imports fine when I kick it off with the import UI. However it will give an Ajax error after importing a few hundred records.

I try to import using cron. That's where it gets confusing to me:

I select "periodic import" -> "as often as possible", uncheck "import on submission" and check "process in the background".

[image]

I then start the import using the UI, it imports some nodes and then stops.

When I manually run "feeds_cron" nothing happens. When I manually run "job_scheduler_con" it showed "Finished processing scheduled jobs (0 sec s, 1 total, 0 failed)." in teh logs and imported more records (but not all).
When I run it again it shows "Finished processing scheduled jobs (0 sec s, 0 total, 0 failed)." and nothing gets imported.

Do I have the correct settings? How are the "periodic import" setting and the "feeds cron" and "job scheduler cron" related?

Is there a setting somewhere that controls how many nodes are processed each time?

Comment: Can you check queue table to see if jobs are added?

Comment: yes, I'm seeing entries for update_fetch_tasks and feeds_source_import

Comment: @MotoTribe did you manage to fix this?

Comment: we just used a custom import script ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the actual site cron? If not, run it.

As for the Ajax errors when running a manual import, are you sure that it isn't continuing to import despite these? My large imports will time out the browser connection when I manually import in feeds, *but* they will actually still continue to process.

Also, could you try changing your setting from "As often as possible" to "Every 30 minutes", to ensure the crons aren't running over each other?

Comment: interesting, it was continuing to import one time but when I tried another time it didn't. So it looks like if "process in the background" is unchecked it will use the batch API instead of the job scheduler? How does Drupal continue processing the batch even after an Ajax error has occurred? Does it use cron?

Comment: Once the job is initiated, cron should trigger firing it off to continue if its stuck, but don't quote me on that I need to look it up again.